# LRU Cache in Node js

Tags: node.js, caching, lru

I need to implement caching for my project(for my organisation), we are planing to have a in-memory LRU caching, I have got some packages but I am not sure about the licensing term, the best I found was this

https://www.npmjs.com/package/lru-cache

but here I am facing some issues when I declare my cache as

```
   var LRU = require("lru-cache")
  , options = { max: 2
              , length: function (n, key) { return n * 2 + key.length }
              , dispose: function (key, n) { n.close() }
              , maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 }
  , cache = LRU(options)
  console.log(cache.length)
  cache.set(1,1)
  cache.set(2,2)
  cache.set(3,3)
  console.log(cache.length)
  console.log(cache.get(1))
  console.log(cache.get(2))
  console.log(cache.get(3))
  console.log(cache)
```

The output which I get for above code is

```
0
NaN
1
2
3
LRUCache {}
```

It doesn't set the max value and it's seems to be infinity
Even If the length is 2 it is not removing the LRU element and adding all three element in the cache

Is any other package available ?, I am also thinking to implement my own caching mechanism, what is the best practice for node js.

Comment: What line of code do you write to get `cache length NaN`? When I copy your code, I get: cache.length === 0. Can you display what you get when you console log the object "cache"?

Comment: @Wing-OnYuen I have modified my question

Comment: Hi, where does this library stores the data? in application's main memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's modify a little bit your code so I can explain better what is wrong.

```
   var LRU = require("lru-cache")
  , options = { max: 2
              , length: function (n, key) { return n * 2 + key.length }
              , dispose: function (key, n) { n.close() }
              , maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 }
  , cache = LRU(options)
  console.log(cache.length)
  cache.set(1,10) // differentiate the key and the value
  cache.set(2,20)
  cache.set(3,30)
  console.log(cache.length)
  console.log(cache.get(1))
  console.log(cache.get(2))
  console.log(cache.get(3))
  console.log(cache)
```

The length function is called every time you set a value in the cache. When you call `cache.set(1,10)`, the function length you defined earlier has as parameters: n (the number 10) and key (the number 1).

So you see here that `key.length` is undefined because a number doesn't have a length property and a sum with `undefined` will be `NaN`. In the documentation the author uses the property length because in general the cache key is a string. You can of course use a number as key but that's what breaks here.

After fixing this issue, you have to pay attention to the function dispose. I quote the author:

> dispose: Function that is called on items when they are dropped from the cache.
>   This can be handy if you want to close file descriptors or do other
>   cleanup tasks when items are no longer accessible.

In this simple case, I don't think you need it so you can remove it.